# How can I make a bash alias for smem -ntkP '[m]yprocess'?

Tags: bash, alias

I would like to make an alias for smem tool.

I need to have the first letter of the process between hooks to let smem subtract himself from the calculation.

So, I would like something like:

```
myalias chromium
```

(which invokes the following command => `smem -ntkP '[c]hromium'`)

I really don't know how to do that. I searched the answer before I ask my question.

Comment: An `alias` can take no arguments, but you can alias just about any command you like. The format is `alias somename='the stuff you want to do'`  That's all there is to it. You can include them in your *.bashrc* if you want the present all the time, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use aliases.  This is a FAQ.  Use a function.

```
sm () {
    smem -ntkP "[${1:0:1}]${1:1}"
}
```

Unlike aliases, functions take arguments, just like scripts; so `$1` is the first argument to the function, and `${1:0:1}` is the first character of that argument. (The `${variable:offset:length}` substring substitution is a Bash extension.)

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comment, If you would like to alias `chromium` and have it invoke `smem -ntkP '[c]hromium'`, then you could do something similar to:

```
alias chromium='smem -ntkP [c]hromium'
```

*though* it is unclear what purpose your single-member *character-class* `[C]` plays in that role... and which probably makes more sense written as:

```
alias chromium='smem -ntkP chromium'
```

**note:** you can include the alias in your `~/.bashrc` or in the system-wide equivalent on your system to have the alias always available. Be careful when overwriting executable names like `chromium` with a second alias (e.g. `alias chromium='...'`) It is better in most cases to choose a name that doesn't conflict (and requires less typing) say `chrom='...'`

Comment: Using a regex which doesn't match itself literally is an age-old technique to have the command not match itself in a process listing.